# Promoting customised SharePoint content between site collections

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, sharepoint-online

Working with SP Online and using SPD 2013 I have been developing some custom lists, with custom new and edit forms, with some custom ribbon action buttons and associated list workflows.

These work nicely in my development site collection, but I now have the need to promote them to a separate UAT site collection (and then ultimately to a further separate Live site collection).

I had started by ensuring my required site columns were set in the UAT site and then saved the required list from the development site collection as a template, which I then imported to the UAT site collection.  I then added this list as a new app and all worked OK.

But then the seams started to come apart - lookup columns did not work (despite the associated lists being created), so I deleted and recreated *those* columns and confirmed the list loaded OK. The default `newitem` form worked OK too, but when I tried to link my custom new item form, I being returned with a "Sorry, something went wrong" error plus

> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this
>   page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For
>   more information, contact your site administrator.

Now, at this point, I'm inclined to step back from this problem to ask for others' advice as to the best and most appropriate way for moving such customized content between site collections.  I accept there will certainly be some re-plumbing required, but am keen to know if there is a right / best way to approach this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the page in maintenance mode? You can do that by adding "?contents=1" after your page, for example:

> htpp://sharepoint/pages/example.aspx?contents=1

You might be able to find out what is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi Greg, and thanks.  I've continued to take a look around for solutions for this and I've reached the conclusion that it is going to be GUID reference related rather than a problem with the web part as such.  Therefore I'm going to take a look at what solutions are our there for moving content programatically between site collections.